# How to append a bootstrap dropdown with a div based on ID?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

In my angular, I have a dropdown component. Here is how it looks like:

```
<div dropdown  placement="bottom left" #dropdown="bs-dropdown" [autoClose]="true" 
  [insideClick]="true" [container]="body">
  <a class="templates-icon" dropdownToggle (click)="toggleTextTemplates();">
    <i #one class="ic-text-templates" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </a>
  <ng-container *ngIf="toggle" >
    <div *dropdownMenu class="templates-container dropdown-menu"
    role="menu" aria-labelledby="button-basic">      
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Here in this example, `container` attribute is set to `body` and therefore the dropdown is bind with the body and visible top of each element.

Now let say I have three layer in my app. `Layer-one, layer-two and layer-three` and they are top of each other. Now I would like to display the dropdown only on layer-two (or imagine in middle layer). So I would like to bind this dropdown with layer-two based on id, so that drodown will be visible on top of `layer one and two`, but not the `layer three`:

```
<div id="layer-one"> 
  some element 1
  <div id="layer-two"> 
    some element 2
    <div id="layer-three"> some element 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can someone please give me an idea, or solution how I can achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to just place the dropdown at layer 2? otherwise you can can use javascript like: getElementByID('#33').innerhtml

or make CSS index rules, where there is a attribute called index: (-1) or (1) etc. for the placement of the dropdown

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).